# How to cast CreateDelegate and assign to Action<T>

Tags: c#

I can assign a method that takes a BaseClass parameter to an Action that takes a SubClass parameter but I cannot use CreateDelegate to do the same. I need this for sending SubClass objects to target methods that take both BaseClass and SubClass parameters.

```cs
class Animal { }

class Cat : Animal { }

void Awake()
{
    Action<Cat> action = null;

    action += TestCat;
    action += TestAnimal;
    action += (Action<Cat>) Delegate.CreateDelegate( typeof( Action<Cat> ), this, "TestCat2" );

    // Casting error!
    action += (Action<Cat>) Delegate.CreateDelegate( typeof( Action<Animal> ), this, "TestAnimal2" );

    // Test
    action.Invoke( new Cat() );
}

void TestCat( Cat param ){ Debug.Log( "Cat" ); }

void TestAnimal( Animal param ) { Debug.Log( "Animal" ); }

void TestCat2( Cat param ){ Debug.Log( "Cat2" ); }

void TestAnimal2( Animal param ){ Debug.Log( "Animal2" ); }
```

The first three assignments to 'action' works fine. But when I cast the result of CreateDelegate I get a nullpointer. What am I missing?

I apologise for the poor title for this question. If you have an improvement please share.

Comment: What does the `CreateDelegate` return? If you store that first in a variable before casting.

Comment: `Action<T>` is not covariant.

Comment: @JeroenvanLangen it returns System.Action`1[Animal]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a limitation of the multicast delegate ([link](https://theburningmonk.com/2011/06/net-tips-make-sure-the-runtime-types-match-when-combining-delegates/)), which you can easily get around with an action wrapper:

```
public void Awake()
{
    Action<Cat> action = null;

    action += TestCat;
    action += TestAnimal;
    action += (Action<Cat>) Delegate.CreateDelegate( typeof( Action<Cat> ), this, "TestCat2" );

    action += new Action<Cat>
    ( 
        (Action<Cat>) Delegate.CreateDelegate( typeof( Action<Animal> ), this, "TestAnimal2" )
    );

    // Test
    action.Invoke( new Cat() );
}
```

[Fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/nu8emy)

Comment: Great! It works! Fiddle seems to compile code a little differently than my environment (Unity3D). In fiddle, the original code I posted throws a "Delegates must be of the same type" error instead of a null pointer. Thank you!