# ArgumentException: Incompatible Delegate Types when adding covariant methods to event

Tags: c#, covariance

I'm seeing very weird behavior when trying to add two methods with different signatures (that are covariant one to the other). It throws an `ArgumentException: Incompatible Delegate Types` when I try to add the second method.

```
public class SomeClass { } // Just a class that inherits from object

public interface GenericInterface<out T> { // An interface with a covariant parameter T
    event System.Action<T> doSomethingWithT;
}

public interface SpecificInterface : GenericInterface<SomeClass> { } // A more specific interface where T = SomeClass

public class ImpClass: SpecificInterface {  // An implementation of the more specific interface
    public event System.Action<SomeClass> doSomethingWithT;
}
```

Basically a simple generic interface where the generic param is covariant, a child interface that assigns a type to the generic, and an implementation of the child interface.

This is the code that throws the exception:

```
protected void Start() {
    ImpClass impObj = new ImpClass();
    GenericInterface<object> genericObj = impObj; // assignment possible because interface is covariant

    impObj.doSomethingWithT += DoSomethingSpecific; 
    genericObj.doSomethingWithT += DoSomething; // this line throws an exception
}

protected void DoSomething(object o) { }
protected void DoSomethingSpecific(SomeClass o) { }
```

Now the code compiles fine, and adding only the more specific or only the more general methods each work fine separately, but if I try to add both, I get the exception.

Doesn't make sense. Any idea why? And any solutions?

Comment: I assume `CovClass` is `ImpClass`? (typo)

Comment: Please see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57367040/2791540)

Comment: @JuanR yes, fixing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I still haven't found an explanation as to why this happens, but I did find a workaround that will let you do this. You'd have to implement accessors to the event and save the delegates in a separate list or hashset instead of using the builtin event implementation.

```
public class ImpClass: SpecificInterface {  // An implementation of the more specific interface
    public event System.Action<SomeClass> doSomethingWithT { 
        add { delegateSubs.Add(value); } 
        remove { delegateSubs.Remove(value); } 
    }

    protected HashSet<System.Action<SomeClass>> delegateSubs = new HashSet<System.Action<SomeClass>>();
}
```

That way you can add/remove delegates of multiple base types of T without any problem. The drawback is of course you'd have to do that for every class that implements the interface, but it guarrantees that whenever you use the events of these classes regardless of T, it will work and not throw an exception.

Answer (score 1):

As for a possible solution, you can use the reference of the specific type to add both handlers and it works fine due to covariance:

```
impObj.doSomethingWithT += DoSomethingSpecific; 
impObj.doSomethingWithT += DoSomething;
```

As for the reason, I can only offer an educated guess: The runtime will not allow handlers with arguments of different types to be attached to a delegate with a generic type, even when the covariance rules are valid as far as the compiler is concerned. And a delegate of a generic type (`System.Action<T>`) is exactly what you are accessing when you use the `genericObj` reference, even though it has already been initialized with a concrete argument type when creating `impObj`.

Comment: Surprisingly, this works. But it kinda beats the point of having a covariant interface if I can't use it... So it doesn't solve the problem.